# Assign same value to multiple variables in single statement

Tags: c#

Is there any way (just out of curiosity because I came across multiple same-value assignments to multiple variables today) in C# to assign one value to multiple variables at once in a single statements?

Something along these lines (pseudocode):

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;

num1 & num2 = 5;
```

Probably not but I thought it was worth asking in case something similar is actually possible!

Answer (score 341, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
num1 = num2 = 5;
```

When using an object property instead of variable, it is interesting to know that the `get` accessor of the intermediate value is not called. Only the `set` accessor is invoked for all property accessed in the assignation sequence.

Take for example a class that write to the console everytime the `get` and `set` accessor are invoked.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var accessorSource = new AccessorTest(5);
    var accessor1 = new AccessorTest();
    var accessor2 = new AccessorTest();

    accessor1.Value = accessor2.Value = accessorSource.Value;

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class AccessorTest
{
    public AccessorTest(int value = default(int))
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    private int _Value;

    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AccessorTest.Value.get {0}", _Value);
            return _Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AccessorTest.Value.set {0}", value);
            _Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This will output

```
AccessorTest.Value.get 5
AccessorTest.Value.set 5
AccessorTest.Value.set 5
```

Meaning that the compiler will assign the value to all properties and it will not re-read the value every time it is assigned.

Comment: Its not weird actually. The logic is as follows:
The assignment operation itself returns a value, which is the value that has been assigned. The sequence of execution is: ``num1 = (num2 = 5)`` and the first assignment which is executed (``num2 = 5``) returns the value 5 to the outside world - which is in turn assigned to num1. This works ad infinitum (``num0 = num1 = num2 = 5``).

Comment: If you want to test it, try `Console.WriteLine(num = 5);`. (Disclaimer: I haven't yet)

Comment: Question: Is this considered bad practice `num1 = num2 = 5`? Does it turn code unreadable if more variables are involved? Sorry to hijack, I didn't want to create a new post just for it.

Comment: There is no correct answer. I use it only scarcely in my program and I could have avoided it.

Comment: Down to coding style I assume then. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: another (separate) example could be to have a third property and do a=b=c and see how many times the "get" accessor of the c property was called

Comment: I had the same doubt just like John wondering about bad practices in this multiple assignation subject.

Comment: And also I'm wondering if there's any performance in this or is it just saving you a line of code?...

Comment: @JosueRocha You can easily validate by compiling and using a decompiler tool and see what is the actual result.

Comment: I am also unsure about it. I like the clarity of `Head.Position = Tail.Position = position`. This means, they do not get the same value by accident, but you really want it to be exactly the same value. This might get lost, if you first assign three values do three properties of Head and afterwards the exact same values to Tail. But I am not sure, if I like it in the long run.

Comment: In response to "Is it considered bad practice?", generally no. I see it quite often in production level code, and most of the time it really helps tidy things up. Just be aware of scenarios where it can make it more difficult to read. Compiled code wise, it's exactly the same as doing it one by one, so it's really up to readability.

Comment: var a = b = c = SomeObject; any change later made to a or b or c will affect all of them.

Comment: @RajeevMenon That's not an effect of the chained/multiple assignment. Had they been written as three separate assignments, changing the assigned object would still affect a, b, and c. But a change such as c = AnotherObject would not affect a or b — again true regardless of the way the variables were initially assigned.

Answer (score 70):

This will do want you want:

```
int num1, num2;
num1 = num2 = 5;
```

'num2 = 5' assignment will return the assigned value.

This allows you to do crazy things like `num1 = (num2 = 5) +3;` which will assign 8 to num1, although I would not recommended doing it as not be very readable.

Answer (score 40):

```cs
int num1 = 5, num2 = 5;
```

Declaring and assigning variables in the same statement.

Comment: Is this a single statement or two statements?

Comment: great answer, but looks weird when "5" is a long string constant.

`string a = "really long string", b = "really long string";`

Answer (score 36):

Something a little shorter in syntax but taking what the others have already stated.

```
int num1, num2 = num1 = 1;
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer because both initialization and assignment can be done in a single statement.

Answer (score 35):

This is now a thing in C#:

```
var (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3);
```

By doing the above, you have basically declared three variables. `a = 1`, `b = 2` and `c = 3`. All in a single line.

Comment: Woah, didn't know this. Can you provide a link to documentation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct "Starting with C# 7.0, you can retrieve multiple elements from a tuple or retrieve multiple field, property, and computed values from an object in a single deconstruct operation. When you deconstruct a tuple, you assign its elements to individual variables. When you deconstruct an object, you assign selected values to individual variables."

Comment: A colleague of mine showed some code that used this syntax in a demo this morning. I've been writing C# since 2003, but this was new to me. Thanks for your comment, and the link to the documentation.

Comment: Don't forget that tuple members can have different types, so this works, too:
 
var (d, i, s) = (6.28, 42, "Hello");

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
num1 = num2 = 5;
```

Note that this won't work in VB.

Comment: Do you know if there is some alternate syntax for VB developers, or is multiple assignment simply not available in VB?

Comment: @cki: AFAIK, it's not supported.

Comment: @ckittel In VB `=` is used both for assignment and equality, so `num1 = num2 = 5` would mean "assign the boolean result of whether or not five is equal to `num2` to the variable `num1`".  Because the `=` operator has these two meanings, there is no way to represent this syntax.  The best you could do is create a function that took in a number of parameters `byref` as well as a value and assigned all of the parameters to that value.

Answer (score 7):

num1 = num2 = 5

Answer (score 6):

```
int num1, num2, num3;

num1 = num2 = num3 = 5;

Console.WriteLine(num1 + "=" + num2 + "=" + num3);    // 5=5=5
```

Answer (score 6):

Your example would be:

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;

num1 = num2 = 5;
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this.

```
num1 = num2 = 5
```