# Can I assign 1 value to numerous strings

Tags: c#, string, .net-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Assign same value to multiple variables in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419252/c-assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables-in-single-statement)

If I have a string declared as,

```
string a,b,c,d......,z;
```

and I want to assign all of them value "69" then what would be **the best approach**.

e.g.

```
a = b = .... = y = z = "69";
```

I dont want to use any array or List.

**Edit**

Would like to know the best approach :)

Comment: ooopss, sorry i wasn't knowing that

Comment: What are you trying to do with this that specifically does not allow for an array?  Is this homework?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed to assign the same string object to multiple variables. You can do it with a single assignment or with multiple ones. You should just get your syntax right.

Comment: LOL nope its not homework, am a developer with an year experience :L

Comment: If you have a large number of variables initialized to the same value, you might be doing it wrong.  Why don't you want to use an array or a list (or a Dictionary which is what I think of when I see variable names a-z)

Comment: @MarkPeters I already mentioned in my question, I have requirement that I can't use Arrays or List Or Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with ""

```
 a = b = .... = y = z = "69";
```

Or

```
int a,b,c,d......,z;
a = b = .... = y = z = 69;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a string:

```
a = b = .... = y = z = "69";
```

Or if it comes from a variable:

```
a = b = .... = y = z = myIntVar.ToString();
```