# How does this C# code work (in aspx.cs class)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm confused at the following code, it looks like it's disabled here?

```
    public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority) {
        authCookie = null;
        userName = password = authority = null;
        return false;
    }
```

shouldn't it look like this?

```
userName =  myName
password =  12345
authority = someAuthority
```

Comment: Basicaly it will `null` all parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419252/c-assign-same-value-to-multiple-variables-in-single-statement

Comment: @walkhard - OK got it!

Comment: -1, because "shouldn't it look like this" is unanswerable without context.

Comment: don't really understand your question. The method you have, as @walkhard says just returns all out parameters and run and results a false. Looks like stub code to me that someone should implement. Also, not sure what you mean by "looks like it's disabled here".

Comment: @DavidHope - stub code, Ok got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# assignment operation "=" returns assigned value, so above code exacutes as follows:

```
userName = (password = (authority = null));
```

or

```
authority = null;
password = authority;
userName = password;
```